# Tying to make unban slash command but finding difficulty in displaying values

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

So let me give you a basic idea of what i'm thinking or trying to do, basically I am making a /unban command in djs v14 and I want the embed to look like [this.](https://sourceb.in/8PLgTrXaXW)

I also want to use buttons **(2 buttons for changing page (5 users in 1 page), and 5 unban buttons each for 1 user)** *(Clicking any one button will unban the user with that number.)*

This is the code i'm using right now:-

```
        
    const { SlashCommandBuilder , EmbedBuilder , PermissionsBitField , ButtonBuilder , ButtonStyle , ButtonComponent } = require('discord.js');
    module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('unban')
        .setDescription('Unbans a user')
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator),
        async execute(interaction, client) {
            const {guild} = interaction;
            const banList = await guild.bans.fetch();
            const UserID = [];
            const UserTag = [];
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder();
    
            banList.forEach(User => {
                UserID.push(User.user.id),
                UserTag.push(User.user.tag)
            });
    
            console.log(UserID);
            console.log(UserTag);
    
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed.setColor('Random').setDescription(`# Banned Users in '${guild}':- \n - ${UserTag[0]} -> ${UserID[0]} `).setTimestamp()]}) // using [0] because it was showing all ids and tags together 
        }
    }
```

I could only get the id and tag of the last user *(Imagine 4 users are banned named -> U1, U2, U3, U4... with their IDs ->Id1 , Id2 , Id3 , Id4 respectively)* when i actually put it in embed and used the command I only saw `U4 - Id4`.

Anyways , wanted to see all the users with their tags and ids but that didnt happen

Edit- Is this even possible?☠️

Answer (score 0):

Just used fields to display IDs beside Tags